# Rendering issues with parallax-effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

I'm trying to create a parallax effect using window.onscroll and scrollTop but I keep running into a rendering issue that looks like I'm receiving the onscroll after the viewport is rendered. As you can see [from this example](http://jsbin.com/afane6/6) (code attached) the movement of the boxes is erratic and choppy.

The behavior is identical in all WebKit based browsers and FireFox.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').each(function() {
    $(this).data('y', $(this).offset().top);
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.box').each(function() {
    var parallax = $(this).data('parallax');

    if (parallax) {
      var y = $(this).data('y');
      var offset = (scroll - y) * parallax;

      $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'translateY(' + offset + 'px)');
    }
  });
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="red box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="green box" data-parallax="0.4">Consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div class="blue box" data-parallax="0.3">Nam consectetur dolor.</div>
```

Comment: Looks smooth to me in Chrome 11 and FF 4 - however with the exception of the first (red) div, I don't see much of the parallax effect. Have you tried with `setInterval` instead of listening to the scroll event?

Comment: What OS are you on? There's quite a visible jerkiness on OSX SL.

Answer (score 2):

Just wondering if it is worth using a pre-made one and not "re-inventing" the wheel?

http://joelb.me/scrollpath/